# How do I convert a short date string back to a DateTime object?

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I have 2 DateTime objects, which I save to a file after using the ToShortDateString() function; the strings look like "12/15/2009". I am stuck on this part now, I want to initialize DateTime object(s) with these strings so I can compare the timespan between the date dates. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("12/15/2009", "MM/dd/yyyy", null);
```

Have a look at

- [DateTime.ParseExact Method (String,
  String, IFormatProvider)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa326711(VS.71).aspx)
- [Easy String to DateTime, DateTime to
  String and Formatting](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/String2DateTime.aspx)

Comment: Depending on current culture, this tends to fail if month or day is a single digit.  You could fix with `M/d/yyyy`, though it's safer to use `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern`, since that's the pattern which `ToShortDateString()` is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.toshortdatestring) as using.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're reading back the dates from the file in string format

```
string date1 = "28/12/2009"; //this will be from your file
string date2 = "29/12/2009"; //this will be from your file
DateTime d1 = DateTime.ParseExact(date1,"dd/MM/yyyy", null);
DateTime d2 = DateTime.ParseExact(date2, "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
TimeSpan t1 = d2.Subtract(d1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `DateTime.Parse(str)`?

Comment: From my experience, this may not work in this case as the format provided is dd/MM/yyyy and will probably get a string is not recognised as a valid datetime. DateTime.Parse(str) works for strings in the format yyyy/MM/dd

Answer (score 1):

I usually try to stick to this when dealing with `DateTime`/`string` transitions:

- When persisting dates in a text format, format it explicitly. Preferably to a standardized format (such as [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)).
- When reading the date back, parse it to a `DateTime` object using the same, explicitly defined format.

This way your code will not fail when used in places where the date format differs from yours, or if the file is created on one locale, and then parsed in another.

```
private static string DateToString(DateTime input)
{
    return input.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
}

private static DateTime StringToDate(string input)
{
    return DateTime.ParseExact(input, "yyyy-MM-dd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract year, month and day, and than use smth like:

```
var dt = new DateTime(Year,Month,Day)
```

or crete an extension method to convert back to dateTime this kind of strings, but in general the body of that extension methad would be smth like this.