# Read date and time value from TextBox and insert into SQL DATE and TIME(7) field in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sql-server, datepicker

I have a `TextBox` in `ASP.NET` that acts as a `DatePicker`, I'm using the `DatePicker` utility as below,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.date-pick').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    });
});
```

The text box is as follows,

```
<asp:TextBox ID="text_date" CssClass="textbox date-pick" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

After i select a date, it displays the date in format `18-10-2016` in the `TextBox`. I have to store this date value in `SQL` database that contains a field with `date` type. I am using the following code for this,

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand insert = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        insert.CommandText = "insert into TableName (MyDate) values (@date)";
        DateTime date;
        date = new DateTime();
        date = DateTime.ParseExact(text_date.Text.ToString(), "dd-MM-yyyy", null);
        insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date);
        con.Open();
        insert.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

But here i am getting the following error in `Console` of the page inspect,

`Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

What am i doing wrong here? I tried using another method also like below but that wont work also,

```
insert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Parse(text_date.Text.ToString());
```

Can someone tell me how to do this..also i want to do the same for `time` data type in `SQL` database. I want to get time value from `TextBox` and store it in database that has `time(7)` format. My time string in `TextBox` will be of the format `hh:mm`.

Comment: Please try : DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("12/15/2009", "MM/dd/yyyy", null); and see if that works. or refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905850/how-do-i-convert-a-short-date-string-back-to-a-datetime-object

Comment: for this i have to change my `DatePicker` format to `MM-dd-yy`?

Comment: Specifying "NULL" means use the current culture. That is causing the problem.

Comment: No. You can change the format MM/dd/yyyy as per your requirement.

Comment: ok i will try and tell u in a while..now i have to leave for home

Comment: Another format you can try is 'yyyy-MM-dd'